# how to display hook [ ] in visual studio on Mac with c#

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

Usually I use VSCode with php, js and framework, I just started to learn C# with Visual Studio on Macbook pro M1 with last feature Visual studio.

However I don't know how to write this [ or ] .

basically to display in VScode "[" we use "option + shift + f5".

I try to delete this bind "option + shif + f5" in configuration without result.

Can someone help me?

Baamz

Answer (score 0):

You have to unlink those shortcuts, in "Text editor" section:

Access the containing statement.
Select to the containing statement.